# JNDI lookup on different application servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, weblogic, jndi

I have an EAR app with an ejb module inside and SomeService:

```
some-ear.ear -> some-ejb.jar -> SomeBean implements ISomeBean
```

In Java EE specification I see that the JNDI name of this bean should be

```
java:comp/env/ISomeService
```

when I deploy my app on **WebLogic 10.3**  then `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ISomeService");` works well

Now I deploy this app on **JBoss 4.2.3** and I see the following in the log:

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.BaseStatelessProxyFactory] Binding proxy for SomeBean in JNDI at some-ear/SomeBean/local
```

OMG!  JNDI name of my bean is `some-ear/SomeBean/local` and
`new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ISomeService");` - not working
`new InitialContext().lookup("some-ear/SomeBean/local");` - works well

Now I deploy my app on **GlassFish 3.1** and I see the following in the log:

```
Portable JNDI names for EJB SomeBean : [java:global/some-ear/some-jar/SomeBean ...
```

Again new JNDI name!

`new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/some-ear/some-jar/SomeBean");` - works well

Can you explain to me why on different AS different JNDI names exist of the same bean and why this JNDI name is different with Java EE specification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JavaEE naming chaos was a long time issue until JavaEE6 spec addressed it.  Now we have standard namespaces for various components of Java EE AppServer. To be fair, you should compare Java EE 6 AppServers, like JBossAS7, Websphere 8, Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: And WebLogic 12c, for that matter.

Comment: The JNDI naming chaos hasn't gone away: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/26451119/1268003](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26451119/1268003)